# Error code :1054 Unknown column, while using joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Hi I am writing a query where i want 2 columns from 2 different sql tables, the 2 tables are "success_ logs" and "defect_logs",The query-

```
SELECT DISTINCT success_logs.sl_frn_rfid_id, defect_logs.sl_frn_rfid_id
FROM success_logs
INNER JOIN  defect_logs dl ON dl.frn_company_id = success_logs.frn_company_id WHERE frn_company_id="abc123";
```

but i am getting an error in the first line
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'defect_logs.sl_frn_rfid_id' in 'field list'
I am not getting where i am going wrong , most of the questions regarding the error was resolved using an alias or their issue was in the "Where" clause. Not getting where the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an alias, I think you need to change the first line from

```
SELECT DISTINCT success_logs.sl_frn_rfid_id, defect_logs.sl_frn_rfid_id
```

to

```
SELECT DISTINCT success_logs.sl_frn_rfid_id, dl.sl_frn_rfid_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you give the tables aliases in the `FROM` clause, you need to use them throughout the query.  That is, `defect_logs` is not recognized.

I would recommend using aliases for *all* the tables, so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sl.sl_frn_rfid_id, dl.sl_frn_rfid_id
FROM success_logs sl INNER JOIN
     defect_logs dl
     ON dl.frn_company_id = sl.frn_company_id
WHERE dl.frn_company_id = 'abc123';
```

Notes:

- Only use `SELECT DISTINCT` if you intend to incur the overhead for removing duplicates.  Usually, it is not necessary.
- The standard SQL delimiter for strings is the single quote, so I recommend that you use that.
- You need to qualify `frn_company_id`. It is in both tables, so it is not clear which column the `WHERE` is referring to.